# list out hadoop yarn jobs that are using highest resources

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, jobs

i want to know how to list out jobs that are using highest memory and CPU, is there any command to list out highest memory used jobs? like i want to know how many vcores and memory a particular job is using.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to gather this data partially from the YARN UI, but I think you'd be better off installing Prometheus node/process exporters, or similar agents, directly on each machine that can gather information about the Linux process usage themselves

Comment: i tried to copy from yarn ui but cpu and cores metrics are not there
 **ID
User
Name
Application Type
Queue
Start Time
Finish Time
State
Final Status
Progress
Tracking UI
Blacklisted Nodes**
 these are the metrics that are available

Comment: You need to go into each individual application page to see its usage of the cluster

Comment: that would be very difficult because there are more than 20k entries. can i consider highest total maps jobs assuming they use more vcores and memory?

Comment: there are like more than 20k job entries and i want to know allocated memory and vcore to those jobs

Comment: Like I said, installing a monitoring agent on each server would be a better solution